# Python 3 and GUI Tkinter logo insertion

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename

def get(name):
  if name in imagelist:
    if imagelist[name][1] is None:
      print('loading image:', name)
      imagelist[name][1] = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[name][0])
        return imagelist[name][1]
      return None

path = '.\logo.gif'
root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "right", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

def open_file():
    """Open a file for editing."""
    filepath = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[("Python files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")]
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    txt_edit.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    with open(filepath, "r") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"Simple Text Editor - {filepath}")

def save_file():
    """Save the current file as a new file."""
    filepath = asksaveasfilename(
        defaultextension="py",
        filetypes=[("Python files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")],
    )
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, "w") as output_file:
        text = txt_edit.get(1.0, tk.END)
        output_file.write(text)
    window.title(f"Simple Text Editor - {filepath}")

def runsomething():
          exec((open_file()).read()) 

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Application")
window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=500, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(2, minsize=500, weight=1)

window.configure(background='grey')

txt_edit = tk.Text(window)
fr_buttons = tk.Frame(window, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=2)
btn_open = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Open", command=open_file)
btn_save = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Save As...", command=save_file)
btn_close = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Close", command=quit)
btn_exec = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Execute", command=runsomething)

btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
btn_save.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
btn_close.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
btn_exec.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5)
fr_buttons.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
txt_edit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

Hi all I am new in python and in tkinter . I am trying to create a small app that will have some buttons and my logo on the grey area at right corner . Everything working fine but I have problems inserting the logo on the same window . The code I have attached is creating a second window with the logo. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Do you wish to have a logo for the tkinter window at the top left corner?

Comment: Hi , I want to have it at top right corner on the same window

Comment: Do you wanna place it below the tab?

Comment: I want to place it at grey area at right side . Below tab yes .

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? IndentationError on line 10

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image on the same window by removing the code that creates the new window (between `def get` and `def open_file`) and add it to the existing window like this:

```
txt_edit = tk.Text(window)
...
btn_exec = tk.Button(fr_buttons, text="Execute", command=runsomething)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(".\logo.gif"))
lbl_logo = tk.Label(window, image = img)

btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
...
lbl_logo.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "nesw")
```